# C++ external libraries issue

Tags: c++, cmake, metis

I have installed an external library named **metis** which resides at "/usr/local/opt/" in my system and I want to link this library to my existing make project, which seems to be difficult. I have tried a few reference links here on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
project(Multi)

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

find_package(CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Core )
  include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )

  include_directories (BEFORE "/include")
  include_directories (BEFORE "/dt")

find_package(MPI)
  include_directories(SYSTEM ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
  SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)
  SET(MPIEXEC_MAX_NUMPROCS "4" CACHE STRING "Maximum number of processors available to run MPI applications.")

find_package(METIS)
    include_directories("/usr/local/opt/metis/include")
    add_subdirectory("/usr/local/opt/metis/include/bin")

add_executable(example example.cpp)
```

I have tried to add the location of the library by using add_subdirectory and include_directories tags but they don't seem to work.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`find_package()` searches for the library in a set of predefined directores, and `/usr/local/opt` is very likely not among those. In this case, since you already know where your library is located, you can tell `find_package()` where to look for it:

```
find_package(METIS REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/opt/metis)
```

---

Also, `add_subdirectory()` works only if the specified directory contains a `CMakeLists.txt`. You need this only if you want to build the library `metis` as part of your build process, and if that directory is the root of the `metis` library, and it used CMake for building too. If you only have the header files and pre-build library files, then you do not need this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me check that.